# How do you increase padding at different levels of d3.js's packed circle layout?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm making a bubble chart of the natural gas wells owned by different energy companies in Pennsylvania using d3.js.

I've built a nested object that first sorts by company, then by wells. A snippet:

```
{
    "name": "Companies",
    "children":[
    {
        "name": "Shell",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "100",
                "lat": 40.543401,
                "lng": -79.162257,
                "company": "Shell",
                "production": "20000"
            },
            {
                "name": "2",
                "lat": 40.608186,
                "lng": -79.369354,
                "company": "Shell",
                "production": "40000"
            },
            {
                "name": "3",
                "lat": 40.558923,
                "lng": -79.630966,
                "company": "Shell",
                "production": "10000"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Range",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "4",
                "lat": 40.431514,
                "lng": -79.466171,
                "company": "Range",
                "production": "25000"
            },
            {
                "name": "5",
                "lat": 40.439876,
                "lng": -80.015488,
                "company": "Range",
                "production": "26000"
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Using `d3.layout.pack`, I've set the padding between circles at 5.

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([w,h])
  .padding(5)
  .value(function(d) {
      return (d.production)
  });
```

But while I'm fine with the inner circles clustering close together, how do I space the upper-level circles out? I've tried assigned `.padding` a function to no avail.

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([w,h])
  .padding( function(d) {
      if (d.depth == 1)
          return 50;
      else
          return 5;
  })
  .value( function(d) {
      return (d.production);
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide us the fiddle?

Comment: The current implementation of the pack layout doesn't allow to variable paddings.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will allow you to modify the padding based on the radius, height or depth of the node:

```
var pack = d3.pack()
  .size([diameter - margin, diameter + margin])
  .padding(function(d) {
      return d.height > 1 ? d.r / 0.35 : 3
  });
```

Comment: It really do the job. Thanks